# Using Amazon AWS Cognito `.well-known/jwks.json` data fails to base64 decode some fields

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-cognito

When using Amazon AWS Cognito **Federated Identities**, and parsing the data at:
`https://cognito-identity.amazonaws.com/.well-known/jwks_uri` which looks like:

```json
{"keys":[
    {"kty":"RSA",
     "alg":"RS512",
     "use":"sig",
     "kid":"ap-northeast-11",
     "n":"AI7mc1assO5n6yB4b7jPCFgVLYPSnwt4qp2BhJVAmlXRntRZ5w4910oKNZDOr4fe/BWOI2Z7upUTE/ICXdqirEkjiPbBN/duVy5YcHsQ5+GrxQ/UbytNVN/NsFhdG8W31lsE4dnrGds5cSshLaohyU/aChgaIMbmtU0NSWQ+jwrW8q1PTvnThVQbpte59a0dAwLeOCfrx6kVvs0Y7fX7NXBbFxe8yL+JR3SMJvxBFuYC+/om5EIRIlRexjWpNu7gJnaFFwbxCBNwFHahcg5gdtSkCHJy8Gj78rsgrkEbgoHk29pk8jUzo/O/GuSDGw8qXb6w0R1+UsXPYACOXM8C8+E=",
     "e":"AQAB"}, 
 ... }
```

This works fine decoding the `n` field using this code (*Kotlin calling JDK 8 Base64 class*):

```kotlin
Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedN.toByteArray())
```

But when using Cognito **User Pools** which has data at a URL in the form of:
 `https://cognito-idp.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/${POOLID}/.well-known/jwks.json`

It has the same type of data, but it will not decode.  Instead I end up with errors such as:

> Illegal base64 character 5f

Since that is an underscore `_` and in the *Base64 URL* alphabet, I tried changing my decoding to:

```kotlin
Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(encodedN.toByteArray())
```

But then the first set of data no longer decodes correctly because it contains `/` and other invalid characters for *Base64 URL* encoding.

Is there a method that can handle both of these `jwks` sets of data with the same decoder?!?

**Note:** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that solutions for interesting problems are shared in SO.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the Amazon AWS Cognito team is using two different Base64 encoding alphabets for basically the same thing.  So you will need to detect which is being used.

If the encoded string ends with `=` or contains `+` or `/` then it is definitely the normal `Base64.getDecoder()`.  If it contains a `-` or `_` then it is definitely the `Base64.getUrlDecoder()`.  Otherwise nothing special is there and it is best to use the `Base64.getUrlDecoder()` because you do not know if the length would need padding or not.

This translates to (*in Kotlin, but logically is applicable to any language*):

```
fun base64SafeDecoder(encoded: String): ByteArray {
    val decoder = if (encoded.endsWith('=') || encoded.any { it == '+' || it == '/' }) {
        Base64.getDecoder()
    }
    else {
        Base64.getUrlDecoder()
    }
    return decoder.decode(encoded.toByteArray())
}
```

This would be a problem for any language that has Base64 decoding in that they might be loose and ignore the invalid character (some do), or they might be strict and throw an exception.  Some test websites for Base64 encoding/decoding exhibit both of these behaviors as well, and the silent ignoring of invalid characters is dangerous.  You would then have an error later using the results of the decoding later.

Comment: Indeed `5f` is an underscore, of the URL-safe variant of Base64

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the apache variant of the Base64 decode (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64).

The decodeBase64(String base64String) method handles both base64 and base64 url safe encodings seamlessly. And the isBase64 method provides a check to detect if a string is encoded in either base64 or base64 url safe.

Comment: Great, in this case wanted to stay with JDK version, although good to know for other projects where commons codec is in the dependencies.