# How can I verify an AWS Cognito OpenID JWT from GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

My users authenticate via an external SAML Provider, after which I call `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` on my server to return the user's federated IdentityId and an OpenID JWT.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html

The `sub` in the OpenID JWT is the user's federated IdentityId, and I want to use the token in future calls to my API where I can unsign and verify the token as a means to identify the user.

However, I can't verify the JWT's signature because there is no UserPoolId, which would normally be used to retrieve the public JWKS found at this url:
`https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json`

1. How can I verify these OpenID tokens?
2. Is it appropriate to use them as an ID token in API calls?
3. If not: The OpenID token can be exchanged on the client (Amplify) for STS credentials. Can those credentials be used to generate some other, more appropriate ID JWT?

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I can't figure it out as well

Answer (score 0):

It took some futzing and a whole lot of Googling but I think I found the pieces to at least answer your question #1.

First, the well known keys when not using User Pools can be found here:

https://cognito-identity.amazonaws.com/.well-known/jwks_uri

(Tip of that hat to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979842/using-amazon-aws-cognito-well-known-jwks-json-data-fails-to-base64-decode-som) that led me to that.)

Second, the AWS Labs GitHub has [a example here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/blob/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt/decode-verify-jwt.py) showing to use the User Pool style well known keys. Swapping it out for the non-User Pool keys works just fine.

For question #3 (skipping ahead) I found no way to do that so for question #2 I ended up writing a API Gateway Lambda Authorizer to do further processing on the token that is returned from GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity to make sure things were on the up and up.